# Start MySQL Server With Java Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, runtime, runtime.exec

I want to start MySQL server using Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() but it's just terminating without starting the server and their is no output from the error and input stream. My code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysqld.exe\"" + 
        " --defaults-file=\"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\my.ini\"" +                 
        " --standalone" +                   
        " --secure-auth");          

StreamReader errorStreamReader = new StreamReader(p.getErrorStream());
StreamReader outputStreamReader = new StreamReader(p.getInputStream());


errorStreamReader.start();
outputStreamReader.start();

if(p.waitFor() == 0) {  

    return true;
}

return false;
```

What I want to achieve is to start the MySQL server from the Java application, the Java application should not block, the Java application should continue execution after starting the MySQL Server.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: I did that but it's still the same, p.waitFor() is returning 0 but the MySQL server is not started and there are no errors.